# Finding week period based on number of days.

Tags: javascript, math

I have dynamic number of `hours`, I want them to round of in weeks
for example suppose I got result of 196 hours

I have convert this into days by:

```
var daysX = hours / 24;
```

now, if `daysx` is equals to or less than 7, it should assign value of week as 1, and if `daysx` is greater than 7 but less than 14 then week should be 2 and so on.

`hours` would be totally dynamic, so I cant apply if else & compare.

Is there any way to dynamically apply week number based on hours?

Any idea would be appreciated! Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could divide the hours by the week length and use [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) for rounding.

```js
function getWeeks(hours) {
    return Math.ceil(hours / 24 / 7);
}

console.log(getWeeks(196)); // two weeks
console.log(getWeeks(169)); // two weeks
console.log(getWeeks(168)); // one week
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let hours = 200;
let result = Math.ceil(hours/(24*7))
console.log(result);
```

This should work fine for you

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply `24` by number of hours divided by `24` passed to `Math.round()` divided by `7`

```
var daysX = Math.round(24 * /* hours as number here */ / 24) / 7
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like :

```
var hours = 196
var days = hours / 24;
var week = Math.floor(days /7);
days = days % 7;
```